# How to display Bootstrap inputs in inline format on horizontal form?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i want to display some form elements in inline during large screen and that same  elements in vertical when screen is small.How  to do this?  please help.please let me know for further information.thanks

[image]

all code in this single html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Horizontal form</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  style="border: 1px solid;  padding: 10px">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
    </div>




    <div class="form-group" >
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="designation">Designation:</label>

      <div class="col-sm-2">

        <select class="form-control  col-xs-2"   id="designation" onchange="updateText('designation')" >
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Designation</option>          
        <option value="04">Chairman</option>                            
        <option value="03">Dean</option>
        </select>       

        <label type="text" class="control-label " for="designationText" >Designation Code </label>              
        <input type="text" value=""  class="form-control" id="designationText" placeholder="Code" />      

      </div>


    </div> 








    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grid to do this, make sure your form has a inline class on it first then do something along these lines:

http://jsfiddle.net/oL2rv8pu/4/

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Horizontal form</h2>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  style="border: 1px solid;  padding: 10px">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">          
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="designation">Designation:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <select class="form-control" id="designation" onchange="updateText('designation')" >
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Designation</option>
                    <option value="04">Chairman</option>
                    <option value="03">Dean</option>
                </select>    
            </div>
            <label type="text" class="control-label col-sm-2" for="designationText" >Designation Code </label>                       <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-control col-sm-2" id="designationText" placeholder="Code" /> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

You may need to enlarge your column sizes to get everything to fit in better, I'd recommend making each row equate to an even number (e.g 2+6 instead of 2+5) so you can divide it between your four columns on larger screens properly (2+2+2+2). As it stands it'll be one column wider than the rest of your page.

Comment: problem with this solution : no space before designation code label

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro I'm 99.9% sure that was just due to incorrect styling and html in the demo code, e.g. that's as far as he got. If not he just needs to put col-md-offset-2 on the first column to move it over.

Comment: no, that's because this label and its field are not in a `.form-group`. I'm trying to find another solution to overcome this

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro he said he wanted to display them inline, that's not inline.

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro I'm just pointing out in the screen shot he took he said he wanted to display all the highlighted elements inline - he didn't say he wanted it to look like that specifically on small screens and just vertical on large screens.

Comment: yes, he said the opposite : inline on large screens and horizontal on small screens.

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro And if the designation code is pushed in with its label above the input like in that example it won't be inline will it. You're assuming he wants it to look like the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to un-nest the `designationText` label/input from `designation` and put them in there own columns but still inside the same form-group as `designation`. Then apply the appropriate amount of columns.

*Note: because these labels/inputs are in a single `form-group`, there isn't the same amount of margin between them as with the other labels/inputs. You can add some CSS inside a media query to fix this disparity.

See example Snippet and [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

```css
.myForm {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #form-group-top {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h2>Horizontal form</h2>


  <form class="form-horizontal myForm" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="designation">Designation:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control" id="designation" onchange="updateText('designation')">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Designation</option>
          <option value="04">Chairman</option>
          <option value="03">Dean</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <label for="designationText" class="control-label col-sm-2" id="form-group-top" for="designationText">Designation Code</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="designationText" placeholder="Code" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```